# Adding user to group in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

When adding a new user to a group in my `SignalR Hub`, how do I check to see if the user has already been added to that particular group? Do I even need to worry about this?

In my `SignalR` based chat app, there are multiple chat rooms and a user can participate in multiple rooms simultaneously. Every time the user clicks a chat room, I set it as the active room and this invokes a call to my `SignalR Hub` to make sure the user is in the group -- using the following line:

```
await Groups.AddAsync(Context.ConnectionId, roomId);
```

I just want to make sure that if my code tries to add a connectionId to a group more than once, I won't get any errors which is why I'm trying to find out if I need to worry about this scenario. If so, how I can check current connectionId's in a particular group.

BTW, I'm coding this in the latest version of `SignalR` which is a part of ASP.NET Core 2.1 Preview-1.

Comment: why don't you just repeat that line twice and test?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes that's possible!** As a result if a client is more than once in a group he will get an event multiple times...

Take a look to source:
https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/1790d6bdf088bab120cd14912d6d625d983fb077/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/DefaultHubLifetimeManager.cs

And

https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR/blob/af286c81bbca00a532ad5297a8f35c9eb1310684/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/HubGroupList.cs

There you can see what's running in the case you call  AddAsync(...)

**Tracking of groups:**

But according tracking of groups I think its the same as in "old" signalr:
You need to keep track of members of a group on your own. SignalR's groups are just for messaging. If you want membership then you need to do your own tracking.

Comment: I already keep track of my users’ membership but these are connection ID’s not user IDs. If I’m not mistaken, users will get different connection ID’s every time they connect. So, if there’s no built in way, then I have to keep track of connection ID’s which can get a bit crazy if/when users get disconnected and reconnect again with new ID’s.

Comment: @Sam Yes, a user gets every time a new connection id. I thinks that's not so difficult. By the way for me is not clear anymore what do you ask. Your question did look like you like to know if there is a build mechanisme and if is it possible to add a client to a group more than once.

Answer (score 0):

As stated here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#overview , there's no method to check if a user belongs to a group.

You have to code that by yourself. The same article includes some examples:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#storedatabase

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#storing-group-membership-in-azure-table-storage

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/working-with-groups#verifying-group-membership-when-reconnecting